# Excel Print Rows WHERE (Selection Criteria)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file has 4 columns (A B C D) with the "Manager" in column A and the Employee numbers in Column B with example info per employee in C & D. What I would like to do is to be able to have a print macro that would print all the employees under each manager on a PDF with the headers repeating at the top. So when the print macro is clicked on, it would ask, "Which Manager"? Then it would be clicked and then it would print the PDF.

Is this possible? I've been researching loops and I was thinking that would be the way to do it but cannot seem to figure out how to replace my "Range" below.  It is example code that I use in another file with static ranges.

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.  P.S. sorry about the code formatting, I cannot seem to get used to Stack Overflow's way of editing it.

```
Sub Dept_BGT_Print()
Range("C14:R45").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"John Dept BGT.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
True
Range("C47:R59").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"HR Dept BGT.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
True
Range("C62:R126").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"Marketing & Sales Dept BGT.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
True
Range("C128:R207").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"Skip Dept BGT.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
True
Range("C209:R250").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"Amy Dept BGT.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
True
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in printing one manager at a time, your best option is probably to just go with an AutoFilter.

```
Sub Dept_BGT_Print()
Dim Sel_Manager As String
'Specify headers to be repeated at the top
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With

'Manager selection through simple Inputbox
 Sel_Manager = InputBox("Which manager?")
'Insert autofilter for worksheet
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
'Select manager defined in inputbox
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Range("D1").End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sel_Manager
 'Select range to be printed and specify manager in filename
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Range("D1").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"Employees for manager " & manager & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, 
 _IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,  OpenAfterPublish:=True

 'remove autofilter
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```